# Moving cart, falling rain, and constant velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, acceleration

A cart moves in a horizontal line with constant velocity and rain (water) starts to fall on it at a rate of $x kg/s$. The force that must be applied to the cart so that the velocity remains constant is the change in momentum divided by the change in time, that is, $mx$.

Now my question is, since the mass increases constantly, how come we must apply a constant force, should we not apply an increasing force with time?

Comment: If I got your problem right you don't need force to accelerate the cart (constant velocity) but only to overcome friction, which doesn't depend on the mass.

Comment: The last part of your first paragraph is wrong, assuming $m$ is mass. The rate of change of momentum with time is the velocity multiplied by the rate of change of mass with time, because velocity times mass is momentum.

Answer (score 1):

$F_{net} = \frac {d}{dt} (mv) = v\frac {dm}{dt} + m\frac {dv}{dt} = v\frac{dm}{dt}$

for constant velocity $v$, mass $m$, rate of change of mass $dm/dt$ (the value you listed as $x$ in the question). Assuming the rate of change of mass is constant, so is $F_{net}$.

The example, when it equates **"net force" = "force that must be applied to the cart"** assumes implicitly that the *only* force acting on the cart is the pushing force, that is, there is no friction resisting the cart's motion.

Your intuition, informed by real life experiences with carts that are not frictionless, is that real carts require constant force to push at constant velocity, and that more massive carts require more force. This is because there is a force of rolling friction. On a level surface, this is $$F_r = -\mu_r |g| m$$ where $\mu_r$ is the coefficient of rolling resistance (a property of the wheels and the road surface), $|g|$ is the absolute value of acceleration due to gravity, and $m$ is the total mass of the cart and load. The minus sign accounts for it being opposite the direction of motion.

A real cart taking on rainwater would then have, for constant velocity:

$F_{net} = v\frac{dm}{dt} = F_{push} + F_r = F_{push} - \mu_r |g| m$

Solve for pushing force: it is the net force plus the force required to overcome friction:

$F_{push} = v\frac{dm}{dt} + \mu_r |g| m$

Thus the rate of change of **pushing force** is indeed directly proportional to the change in mass, even though the **net force** is constant.

$\frac{d}{dt} F_{push} = \frac{d}{dt} (v\frac{dm}{dt} + \mu_r |g| m) = \mu_r |g| \frac{dm}{dt}$

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the help! Now I got it and here is how I understand it so that someone else wondering could perhaps understand:

Since the velocity of the cart is changing constantly as the mass is changing constantly, then for us to resist this change, we must be constantly applying  N (Newtons).

Let us say for the first second, we must apply force  N to get back to the initial velocity *v*. This is because the force that the rain exerts is given by this, hence we must exert an equal but opposite force to stop acceleration. Then let's say in time *t* = 2 seconds the velocity would change by the same amount as at time *t* = 1 second, now since the change is the same, we must apply the same amount of force again,  N. Therefore, this is the constant resultant force that will always be applied to the cart so that it maintains a constant velocity.